Error Connect-SPOService : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send
For some reason jut started geting this error when trying to connect to an admin site using powershell
  Connect-SPOService : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.


Also for some reason the site to download SP Online Shell is down here below.It doesn't work
https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=35588
Thanks in Advance
